# MVC Routing - wildcard URL, but constrained

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I basically want to do this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Pass-through",
  "/api/{*url}",
  new { controller = "PassThrough", action = "PassThroughToApi" });
```

and the controller I am directing the request to has:

```
public ContentResult PassThroughToApi(string url = null)
```

However, I want to be able at the same time to constraint the URL. Such as:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Pass-through",
  "/api/v1/some/specific/address/{whatever}/{parameters}",
  new { controller = "PassThrough", action = "PassThroughToApi" });
```

But I still want the Controller to get the requested URL as a variable and I don't care about getting the actual parameters, as long as the URL matches the pattern. Or should I just get the requested URL from another place, like a context, instead of being passed to it as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create [custom route constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs)

```
public class ApiRedirectingConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private string _matchUrl;

    public ApiRedirectingConstraint(string matchUrl)
    {
        _matchUrl = matchUrl;
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        string url = (string)values["url"];

        bool isMatch = true;
        //check url for specific match with _matchUrl

        return isMatch;
    }
}
```

and assign it to the `Pass-through` route

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Pass-through",
    "/api/{*url}",
    new { controller = "PassThrough", action = "PassThroughToApi" },
    new { apiRedirect = new ApiRedirectingConstraint("/api/v1/some/specific/address/{whatever}/{parameters}") }
);
```

Comment: I need to be able to specify the route (constraints) in the Routing bootstrap, e.g.  at `routes.MapRoute`. I wonder, maybe if I pass the actual constraint URL as a parameter to the `ApiRedirectingConstraint` ctor

Comment: @HristoYankov Was it helpful? Or maybe you need something else?